# How to add recipes to cooking recipe programs (Gourmet Recipe Manager)

Tags: 11.10, recipe

I am testing out the **Gourmet Recipe Manager** but the instructions to add many recipes in one step are in an alien language since I have not yet been able to add a recipe. Is there a place where I can just simply import a file and it adds many recipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have luck with some of the files available here:

http://mc6help.tripod.com/RecipeLibrary/RecipeLibrary.htm

Just download the txt files and import with Gourmet, there are many recipes in one txt file.

and here: http://www.grassrootsrecipes.com/

All the Above are Mastercook ascii files, there may be some encoding issues

Some Meal-Master files that Gourmet recipe Manage Can Import are here:

http://home.earthlink.net/~darkstar105/